# Mule ESB and basic authentication

Tags: mule, basic-authentication

I wrote a flow accepting JSON, now I want to add http authentication.  I want to accept HTTP basic authentication uid and pw.

So I am starting with a Hellow World program first, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
    <flow doc:name="HelloWorldFlow1" name="HelloWorldFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message." doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081"/>
        <set-payload doc:description="This processor sets the payload of the message to the string 'Hello World'." doc:name="Set Payload" value="Hello World"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

And I test with the following program:

```
C:\curl>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u uida:pw -d {"first":"Steven"
} http://localhost:8081
Hello World
C:\curl>
```

This works, as there is no basic auth configured within th eflow, so it ignores the "-u uid:pw" I sent on the curl command

Now I change the flow as follows ( I put 'uid' in the 'Http Settings->User' field, and 'pw' in the 'Http Seetings->Password' field on the GUI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
    <flow doc:name="HelloWorldFlow1" name="HelloWorldFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message." doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" password="pw" user="uid"/>
        <set-payload doc:description="This processor sets the payload of the message to the string 'Hello World'." doc:name="Set Payload" value="Hello World"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Now when I test I get the following:

```
C:\curl>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u uida:pw -d {"first":"Steven"
} http://localhost:8081
Cannot bind to address "http://127.0.0.1:8081/" No component registered on that
endpoint
```

I have done this repeatedly, but I get the same response.

Is there another field that I should have set?  Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user` and `password` attributes are ineffective on inbound HTTP endpoints, they only work on outbound.

Mule uses Spring Security for authentication. This is detailed in the user guide: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager , including an example of the `http-security-filter` that you need to put in the HTTP inbound endpoint.

Comment: I am trying to implement the spring solution now, but was wondering why the username and password only work on the outbound HTTP.  Does that mean that it is providing the uid and pw for the server is sending the response to (which would seem unlikely)  ?

Comment: The `username` and `password` attributes on outbound HTTP endpoints are used to perform HTTP Basic Auth on remote HTTP servers Mule connects to.

Comment: inbound auth typically involves multiple users/pws and sometimes various security realms. So that requires setup external to the component.